# Desktop login sound doesn't play after login

Tags: sound, login

I've been looking around for a solution for this, but didn't found it.

I remember that from USB (Live Session) Ubuntu had all its sounds. But after installed and after login, desktop-login sound never play.

I've been looking at dconf-tool without success. Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than deleting the whole .dconf folder, just open dconf-editor and navigate to:

```
org.gnome.desktop.sound
```

Change the value of "theme-name" to "ubuntu"

Also check to make sure that "GNOME Login Sound" is checked in "Startup Applications".

I've also filed a bug about this:

- http://pad.lv/883677

Comment: I cannot find the .dconf folder in my Home, though I have enabled hidden files. Where is the exact location?

Comment: Run these two commands:
`sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`
`dconf-editor`

Comment: I think it would be `sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` `dconf-editor`

Comment: How to add the GNOME login sound in startup applications if it is not there.I mean what is the command for it.I know how to add,just need the command.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this post at Ubuntuforums : [Oneiric Login Sound](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863638)

This workaround solved the problem for me.
Attention : Deleting that folder you are going to miss some of your configurations such as unity launchers , desktop background...

Answer (score -1):

Run in the terminal these command:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/* /usr/share/sounds/
```

Comment: What does this do? You should elaborate on how this will fix the problem and why it might need to be done.