# Login Sound busted Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, sound, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop login sound doesn't play after login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65502/desktop-login-sound-doesnt-play-after-login)

I was trying to change my login sound..didnt work. I tried changing back to original still no cigar. Went to start up application to change the command for GNOME Login sound to a direct link to the login sound file...still did'nt work. Current command for GNOME Login Sound is /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo. Any idea how I can get my login sound to start working again?

PS to change the sound i followed this procedure...http://peeqsource.com/2012/changing-login-sound/

Answer (score 0):

Did you recently install all updates and reboot? Maybe you have to unmute the volume once. My sound was fixed installing updates last week.

Comment: Everything is up to date. Unmute...? hmmm i'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

The basic rule of creating sound files for ubuntu is to keep the name and the extension. If you need a sound converter then use "Sound Converter" available in Ubuntu Software Center or Audacity.

Check whether you have kept the exact names and file extension (.ogg).

Comment: I did both..I created a custom audio file through Audacity...but for some odd reason audacity did not give me an option to convert the file to .ogg. So what I did was use Ubuntu's sound recorder (because those automatically save in .ogg) and re-record the sound file. It worked. And followed those steps in the link I provided. Its weird to. When I start Ubuntu up...It play what sounds like a very very compressed audio file for a split second. Don't know if thats a bug or what but it always happens logging in and logging out. :\